# Polly Timeout optimistic using HttpClientFactory. How can I use cancellation token?

Tags: c#, timeout, dotnet-httpclient, polly, policywrap

I would like to understand how to implement an optimistic timeout policy with Polly by using the `HttpClientFactory`.

In the examples on the net, the timeout policy is used when calling asynchronous methods to be able to pass the cancellation token. But if I set the timeout policy from configure services, as indicated in [the guide](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory)), how do I manage the cancellation token?

In example code, from guide linked, I see this:

```
var timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(10); // Timeout for an individual try

serviceCollection.AddHttpClient("GitHub", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60); // Overall timeout across all tries
})
.AddPolicyHandler(retryPolicy)
.AddPolicyHandler(timeoutPolicy);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should [chain](https://github.com/peter-csala/resilience-service-design/blob/main/resilience.md#esc) the retry and timeout policy into a combined policy.

You have two options:

#### `Wrap` method

```
.AddPolicyHandler(retryPolicy.Wrap(timeoutPolicy))
```

- `timeoutPolicy` is the inner policy so it applied for each and every attempt separately
- `retryPolicy` is the outer policy, so it's overarching the timeout policy
- Note the ordering matters (I will detail it in a later section)

#### [`PolicyWrap`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyWrap) class

```
.AddPolicyHandler(Policy.Wrap(retryPolicy,timeoutPolicy))
```

- the first argument is the most outer policy
- the last argument is the most inner policy

---

#### Ordering does matter

You should be aware that the following two combined policies are very different:

```
Policy.Wrap(retryPolicy,timeoutPolicy)
Policy.Wrap(timeoutPolicy, retryPolicy)
```

- In the first case you have a *local* timeout, which is applied for each and every retry attempt
- In the second case you have a *global* timeout, which is applied for the overall retry activities

Pushing this idea forward you can avoid to set the `Timeout` property of HttpClient by defining a global timeout as well:

```
var localTimeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(10);
var globalTimeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(60);
var resilientStrategy = Policy.Wrap(globalTimeoutPolicy, retryPolicy, localTimeoutPolicy);

serviceCollection.AddHttpClient("GitHub", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.github.com/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
})
.AddPolicyHandler(resilientStrategy);
```

---

**UPDATE #1** Optimistic timeout

Polly's Timeout does support both [optimistic](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout#optimistic-timeout) and [pessimistic](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Timeout#pessimistic-timeout) timeouts. In other words Polly can try to cancel those to-be-wrapped methods that does anticipate a `CancellationToken` (optimistic) as well those methods that doesn't (pessimistic). The default is the former.

In case of optimistic you have two options:

- Let the policy do the cancellation

```
await policy.ExecuteAsync(
   async ct => await httpClient.SendAsync(..., ct),
   CancellationToken.None);
```

- Or combine / chain it with your custom CTS

```
await policy.ExecuteAsync(
   async ct => await httpClient.SendAsync(..., ct),
   cancellationSource.Token);
```

If you register your named/typed client during the startup then you can only use the first option. Since the `policy.ExecuteAsync` will be called on your behalf (implicitly).

If you register a typed client and you define the policy inside that client then you are making an explicit call of the `ExecuteAsync` where you can decide which version to use.